# Как увеличить размер миниатюры wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Подскажите пожалуйста как увеличить размер миниатюры. Вот код. Откуда оно просит миниатюру? Где найти?

```
<div class="neer_testimonial_grid_carousel_slider owl-carousel <?php if($theme == 'dark'){ echo 'neer_testimonial_dark_theme'; } elseif($theme == 'lite') { echo "neer_testimonial_lite_theme"; } ?>">
            <?php foreach($neer_testimonial_carousel_list as $testi_carousel) : ?>
                <div class="neer_testimonial_grid">

                    <?php if($testi_carousel->neer_testimonial_carousel_thumbnail) :
                    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src($testi_carousel->neer_testimonial_carousel_thumbnail, 'neer-testimonial-thumb');
                    if(($thumb) && !empty($thumb[0])) :  ?>
                        <div class="neer_testimonial_grid_medium">
                            <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( $thumb[0] ); ?>" alt="Testimonial Thumb" class="img-responsive">
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="neer_testimonial_grid_content_column">
                            <div class="neer_testimonial_grid_content">
                                <?php echo wpautop( $testi_carousel->neer_testimonial_carousel_content ); ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="neer_testimonial_grid_author_content">
                                <h2><?php echo $testi_carousel->neer_testimonial_carousel_author_title; ?></h2>
                                <p><?php echo $testi_carousel->neer_testimonial_carousel_author_sub_title; ?></p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Размер выводимой миниатюры задается `neer-testimonial-thumb` в `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`. Этот размер определён в вашей теме примерно таким кодом

```
add_image_size( 'neer-testimonial-thumb', 400, 200, true );
```

Где 400 (пикселей) - ширина, 200 - высота.

Вы можете задать новый размер (например, `my-testimonial-thumb`) аналогичным кодом и подставить его в `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`. После этого потребуется перегенерация всех миниатюр с помощью плагина Regenerate Thumbnails.

Также можно вызвать `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` указав размер в виде массива.

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(
    $testi_carousel->neer_testimonial_carousel_thumbnail,
    array(500, 300) );
```

В примере задан размер 500x300.

Comment: Спасибо! Я в functions нашел neer-testimonial-thumb и пересоздал миниатюры. Так как Вы и подсказали.